# Python requests pull not always retrieving data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

To practice programming, I am trying to help a friend review a subreddit's data via webscraping and requests and bs4. (I prefer requests for this task since I am moving this script over to my Rasberry Pi and don't think its little heart could even get Chrome installed.

I am running into an issue where my requests only outputs the results *sometimes*, meaning it will pull the name and url of the post, say 1 out of 5 times when run. When the request returns no data, it doesn't return an error, the program just stops.

```
from time import sleep
import requests 
import os
import re 

i = 1 
selections = "" 
r = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/hardwareswap/search?q=Vive&restrict_sr=1", timeout = None) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 
results = soup.find_all('a', attrs = {'data-click-id':'body'}) 

textitems = []
for result in results:
    textitems.append(result.text.strip())

for result in textitems:
    print(result)

links = soup.find_all('a', attrs = {'data-click-id':'body'}) 

for link in links:
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Any thoughts as to why this happens? My initial thoughts were it was either due to a reddit policy or an invalid URL.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already rule out that it could be due to a Reddit policy? If so, why? Why don't you use the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/)?

Comment: Hi @HernánAlarcón I am just assuming this because it will run the script once or twice and then stop working, but it usually works well for a few runs. I believe you may be right - currently looking into the Reddit API docs now. If someone has the answer, it would be great knowledge to know why this doesn't work...